# Why is there a left padding in a cell using FPDF in php?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am printing a cell using the FPDF(http://www.fpdf.org/) class in php. The cell should be placed into the top left corner.

Everything works great, except that a left padding is added inside the cell.

Here is my code:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'mm', array(50.8,88.9));
$pdf->addPage('L', array(50.8,88.9));
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(100,'default');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);    
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8.5);

$pdf->SetXY(0, 0); //sets the position for the name
$pdf->Cell(0,2.98740833, "Your Name", '1', 2, 'L', false); //Name
```

Here's a screenshot of the PDF that is outputting with FPDF:

[image: Screenshot of PDF output with FPDF]

Why is there a left padding in a cell using FPDF in php and how can I remove the padding?

Comment: You really should checkout [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). I don't believe FPDF is being maintained anymore.

Comment: I took your advice and created the same page with TCPDF and I am now getting a top and left padding within the cell. I have posted the code and screenshots here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483326/why-is-there-a-left-and-top-padding-in-a-cell-using-tcpdf-in-php

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't saying it would necessarily fix the issue, just that TCPDF is a more modern and maintained package than FPDF. I used to use FPDF, but have found TCPDF to be more useful.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is super old, but I had and fixed the same issue so maybe someone will find it useful.

There's a property in the FPDF class called $cMargin, which is used to calculate the x-offset of the text before it gets printed within the cell, but there doesn't appear to be a setter for it. It's a public property, so after you've instantiated your FPDF class, just call:

```
$pdf = new fpdf('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->cMargin = 0;
```

And your cells won't have that padding on the left any more.

Comment: In FPDF 1.8.1 This property is protected, so this answer will not work.

Comment: @AnwarNairi so what we will have to do to get padding in cell?

Comment: For the Python pyfpdf equivalent you can set `pdf.c_margin = 0`

Answer (score 8):

Small fix updateproof

```
<?php
require("fpdf.php");

class CustomFPDF extends FPDF{
    function SetCellMargin($margin){
        // Set cell margin
        $this->cMargin = $margin;
    }
}
?>

<?php
$pdf = new CustomFPDF();
$pdf->setCellMargin(0);
?>
```

Comment: A small aside, the cell margin has no effect if the cell is set to Center alignment

Comment: This is the only correct way to fix this issue with the latest version of FPDF, as cMargin is now a protected property. Thank you for the great fix @Vince!

Answer (score 2):

I can't work out how to remove the padding.

As a workaround, it is useful to know that it seems to be 1mm, regardless of font size. The same padding is applied at the right edge with right aligned text.

Answer (score 2):

i've ran into the same problem. Only the 1st line has this unwanted margin, so my workaround was this:

```
  $pdf->Ln(); //workaround for 1st line
  $pdf->Cell(..);
```

Comment: Solved my issue too, you can pass the height value to the `Ln(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `SetMargins(0,0)`?

> **SetMargins**

`SetMargins(float left, float top [, float right])`

> Description
>
> Defines the left, top and right margins. **By default, they equal 1 cm.** Call this method to change them.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setmargins.htm

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I am actually using that function already. I had not listed it here because I didn't think it was important. I have now updated all the functions I am using so that you have a better idea.

Comment: This function is for setting the margin for the entire page, not each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use SetMargins before AddPage

example:

```
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(23, 44, 11.7);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
```