# Why is there a left and top padding in a cell using TCPDF in php?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am printing a cell using the TCPDF([http://www.tcdf.org/](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html)) class in php. The cell should be placed into the top left corner.

Everything works great, except that a left and top padding is added inside the cell.

Here is my code:

```
require_once('../config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8.5, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage('L', array(50.8,88.9));
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(100,'default');

$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
$pdf->Cell(0,2.98740833, "Your Name", '1', 2, 'L', false); //Name

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Here's a screenshot of the PDF that is outputting with TCPDF:

[image: Here's a screenshot of the PDF that is outputting with TCPDF:]

Here's a screenshot of the same cell at 300% magnification:

[image: Close-up of the padding in the cell]

How can I remove the unwanted padding?

///***EDIT***///

I managed to remove the left padding by using the setCellPaddings() function:

```
$pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
```

I am however still getting padding above and below the text within the cell:

[image]

I can increase the size of the cell, but when I try to make the height of the cell smaller to try and close it in on the text, the cell won't get any smaller than the current size. How can I decrease the height of the cell or remove the unwanted top and bottom padding of the cell?

Comment: In my case I just wanted to remove the left and right padding, so my code is `$pdf->setCellPaddings(0,'','',0);`. Thanks to your question and answer I could easily figure this out...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, that it is not padding, but space for letters which extend below the baseline (e.g. "g"), accents, subscripts and superscripts.

I tried your code with some accented letters in the text. This is the result:
[image: tcpdf test]

Relevant:
- [Baseline (typography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29)
- [Subscript & Superscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript)

Answer (score 1):

On an additional note, you can decrease the height of the cell by passing TRUE for the ignoreMinHeight parameter in the Cell function.